# Client violating MSS value agreed during handshake

Tags: networking, tcp

During a TCP connection, what happens if client sends a segment whose size is greater than MSS value agreed during handshake ? Does the connection terminates ? Can it cause an error in server ?

For eg - Let client during handshake agreed that its MSS value is 1200 and after that it sends packets with size say 1600.

Any further links for reading are appreciated.

Comment: How could a client do that? Short of a bug in the TCP implementation?

Comment: I was just wondering what would happen if that happens and does a TCP server has built in mechanisms to cope up with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSS value is there to avoid packet fragmentation. It is calculated as MTU - IP header (20 byte) - TCP header (20 byte), where MTU is the interface's hardware limitation. Say, regular MTU on Ethernet networks is 1500, leaving us with MSS value of 1460.

Now, if the server in question is not something you are fiddling with, and it announces MSS = 1200, you should consider this be a physical constraint. That is, if your client application sends (via standard API) a buffer of 1600 bytes in size, the kernel will form two packets.

If the server in question is yours, and it has physical ability to receive large MTU (say, 1640), but for some vague reasons you force it's TCP to announce MSS = 1200, and then your client uses MSS = 1600 ignoring the announcement, this is perfectly fine: you will see no errors. There are some relevant experiments you could find interesting, e.g. http://hacked10bits.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/forcing-higher-mss-to-improve-tcp.html

Comment: Let us say MSS = 1200 is a physical constraint and I force MSS = 1600, I believe packet would reach the server ( IP layer would reassemble fragmented packets before giving it to the TCP layer). So now would server be able to handle this packet ? Would it crash or abort connection or connection would go on normally, with the difference being client's packets getting fragmented ? And do you know how to I can forge packet myself ?

Comment: In order to send an MSS = 1600 it should not be a physical constraint at the sender. If receiver is capable of MSS = 1200 AND fragmentation occurs in transit, this is fine and transparent for application.

Comment: If you can also give some reference it would be great. Thanks :)